# angular template image url phasing

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

So I'm working on a site with angular and I've run into an issue we have image urls that have values like `%WIDTH%` and `%HEIGHT%` in them. We want to be able to set the vales in these for the image url so they would be 650 and 200 respectfully. Any ideas?

Comment: please post more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse your image urls and replace WIDTH & HEIGHT you can use a filter

```
app.filter('srcFill', function() {
        return function(item, data) {
          item = item.replace(/%HEIGHT%/g, data.height);
          item = item.replace(/%WIDTH%/g, data.width);
          return item;
        }
      });
```

if your image is like :

```
http://example.com/images/%WIDTH%/%HEIGHT%/hello.jpg
```

and your img tag will look like following

```
<img ng-src="{{ imageUrl | srcFill : {width:650,height:200} }}">
```